# Какая библиотека в C# подключает все библиотеки?

Tags: c#, библиотеки

Как называется библиотека для подключения всех библиотек в C#, если такая есть. В C++ такая библиотека называется <bits/stdc++.h>. Есть ли такая же в C#?

Answer (score 4):

Подобной функциональности в .NET(C#) нет. На мой взгляд, к счастью.

Аргументирую: библиотек для .NET сотни-тысяч. В большинстве случаев библиотеку можно воспринимать как отдельный файл DLL. Со всеми бинарными кодами, это не заголовочный файл, как в C++.

Крайне неразумно включать в свой проект гигабайты ненужных DLL, разработчику предлагается прицельно указать какие библиотеки он будет использовать, какие версии библиотеки.

К тому же процесс подключения нужной библиотеки к проекту зачастую максимально автоматизирован, особенно при использовании Resharper и сводится к нажатию Alt+Enter, на выбор предлагается список из библиотек, содержащих требуемый класс/функцию. Если в списке одна библиотека, то её подключение производится вообще без вопросов. IDE Visual Studio тоже почти "дотягивает" до уровня Resharper в этой части. В общем, всё максимально просто, IMHO.

Comment: Стоит, наверное, добавить про сам механизм подключения библиотеки. В `C#` нет препроцессора, и подобное "включить все" просто невозможно при данном подходе. Директивы `using` это не включение заголовочного файла, как в `C/C++`, а просто упрощение жизни, чтобы не приходилось писать полное имя класса со всеми пространствами имен. Само "подключение" происходит на уровне файла проекта через `PackageReference/ProjectReference/Reference`.

Answer (score 4):

Файл `<bits/stdc++.h>` подключает не "все библиотеки", а все (основные) заголовочные файлы стандартной библиотеки. Иными словами, этот файл подключает стандартную библиотеку и ничего более.

В языке C# стандартная библиотека всегда подключена к проекту (если только не шаманить с настройками сборки и параметрами компилятора) - а потому никакие аналоги `<bits/stdc++.h>` просто не нужны.

Comment: Второй абзац прозвучал максимально странно. О чем он?

Comment: @SelfishCrawler о том, что аналог этого файла в C# просто не нужен.

Comment: В пустом проекте по умолчанию не подключено ничего. Все библиотеки подключаются в зависимостях, а с помощью using'a указываются используемые пространства имен. В консольном же проекте по умолчанию в Visual studio тоже много чего не подключено.

Comment: @SelfishCrawler вот что автоматически подключается в зависимостях у **пустого** консольного проекта: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJJvo.png

Comment: @SelfishCrawler и да, большинство этих библиотек - просто форварды на corelib/mscorlib/…, которая подключается автоматически компилятором и без специального флага не отключается.

Comment: @SelfishCrawler Можно и не использовать using, но тогда у каждого вызова какого либо метода нужно будет писать полный путь пространства имен.

Comment: [Вот](https://i.imgur.com/ZxMnQRa.png) что добавляется в зависимости пустого проекта не core

Comment: @SelfishCrawler ага, и там есть неявная mscorlib, в которой есть большинство из перечисленного на скриншоте выше.

Comment: @SelfishCrawler но, вообще говоря, не Core проекты давно уже устарели. Никто не мешает использовать новую систему сборки даже если на выходе нужен проект для старого фреймворка.